# Why to use JBoss for Grails deployment?

Tags: grails, jboss

I'm working on the project that uses Grails as Web framework and JBoss for deploying web-applications. JBoss allows to configure connection to database and then Grails could use JNDI datasource. However in our project we don't use JNDI datasources, we configure data sources for both development and production in DataSource.groovy. Other JBoss services are not used also.

I understand that if we are using JNDI datasource connections then we may benefit if several grails applications are deployed, because in this case there is no need for each grails application to establish its own connection.

So I wonder is there any sense to use JBoss instead of, say, Tomcat or Jetty, if not using it's services?

Comment: is that the only application deployed on the server?

Comment: no, there are several grails applications

Comment: ok, but they are all the same type, I was wondering whether other applications used JBoss services, and you confirm that the answer is no.

Comment: Except web-applications there are several standalone applications and for accessing database they use spring/hibernate-not JBoss provided

Answer (score 2):

JBoss is a J2EE container. Compared to Tomcat which is a Servlet and JSP container only, the JBoss AS has a lot more features. Thus JBoss is also "heavier" than Tomcat, and depending on the size of your project this may not fit well with your development team since it has a longer development cycle (I heard there were a lot of improvements in JBoss 7, haven't tried it yet though.)

If you are not using any of the J2EE container features (JMS, EJB, etc.) then you could be fine going with Tomcat using a grails application. We use Tomcat at work for hosting one of our web applications.

In regards to connection pooling managed by JBoss, Tomcat can also do that. Take a look at this [documentation page](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jndi-datasource-examples-howto.html). Hope this helps.